# Planned comparisons significant but interaction non-significant

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, interaction, planned-comparisons-test

I ran a simple linear mixed model using `lmer` on a dataset for participants who had been randomly assigned to one of two conditions and were measured at baseline, post-intervention, and at a follow-up on a continuous outcome.

The model took the form `lmer(outcome ~ timepoint * condition + (1|cluster/ID), data = data)`

The results indicated that there was no significant interaction for `timepoint*condition`. However, I checked the group comparisons using `emmeans` that were planned to contrast the marginal mean group scores at post-intervention and also at follow-up, and both of these comparisons are significant.

Since the planned comparisons drew on the model generated in the first step, how is it that the interaction is non-significant but those two comparisons are significant?

The results of the model and then the comparisons are below:

```
>     ## Model ##
>     lmer(outcome ~ timepoint * condition + (1 | cluster/ID), data = data)

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: outcome ~ timepoint * condition + (1 | cluster/ID)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 1294.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.03115 -0.49191 -0.01708  0.51935  2.43162 

Random effects:
 Groups            Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID:cluster        (Intercept) 1.6674   1.291   
 cluster           (Intercept) 0.1176   0.343   
 Residual                      3.0743   1.753   
Number of obs: 302, groups:  ID:cluster, 106; cluster, 6

Fixed effects:
                                    Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                        5.161e+00  3.878e-01 4.015e+00  13.309  0.00018 ***
timepoint1                         2.846e-01  3.589e-01 2.044e+02   0.793  0.42868    
timepoint2                         3.688e-03  3.615e-01 2.052e+02   0.010  0.99187    
conditionTreatment            4.325e-01  5.197e-01 5.582e+00   0.832  0.43945    
timepoint1:conditionTreatment 6.619e-01  4.941e-01 2.009e+02   1.340  0.18189    
timepoint2:conditionTreatment 6.067e-01  4.974e-01 2.017e+02   1.220  0.22393    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) tmpnt1 tmpnt2 trtmnT tmp1:T
timepoint1  -0.427                            
timepoint2  -0.423  0.478                     
conditionTr -0.746  0.318  0.316              
tmpnt1:conT  0.310 -0.726 -0.347 -0.453       
tmpnt2:conT  0.308 -0.347 -0.727 -0.450  0.485


## Comparisons ##
>     mod_outcome <- lmer(outcome ~ timepoint * condition + (1 | cluster/ID), data = data)

>     emm_outcome <- emmeans(mod_outcome, specs = pairwise ~ condition:timepoint, adjust = "none")
>     emm_outcome$contrasts
 contrast                                    estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 Control timepoint0 - Treatment timepoint0    -0.1755 0.352 292  -0.498  0.6190
 Control timepoint0 - Control timepoint1      -0.2939 0.354 203  -0.829  0.4079
 Control timepoint0 - Treatment timepoint1    -1.1232 0.354 292  -3.172  0.0017
 Control timepoint0 - Control timepoint2      -0.0162 0.357 205  -0.045  0.9638
 Control timepoint0 - Treatment timepoint2    -0.7938 0.356 292  -2.230  0.0265
 Treatment timepoint0 - Control timepoint1    -0.1184 0.364 292  -0.325  0.7452
 Treatment timepoint0 - Treatment timepoint1  -0.9478 0.338 196  -2.806  0.0055
 Treatment timepoint0 - Control timepoint2     0.1593 0.366 292   0.435  0.6641
 Treatment timepoint0 - Treatment timepoint2  -0.6183 0.340 197  -1.821  0.0701
 Control timepoint1 - Treatment timepoint1    -0.8293 0.366 292  -2.268  0.0241
 Control timepoint1 - Control timepoint2       0.2777 0.366 196   0.758  0.4494
 Control timepoint1 - Treatment timepoint2    -0.4999 0.367 292  -1.361  0.1747
 Treatment timepoint1 - Control timepoint2     1.1070 0.368 292   3.009  0.0029
 Treatment timepoint1 - Treatment timepoint2   0.3294 0.341 196   0.966  0.3352
 Control timepoint2 - Treatment timepoint2    -0.7776 0.370 292  -2.104  0.0363

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the model and a summary of the results that you cite. I suspect that this has to do with the way that the time variable was coded into your model, but without more information it's hard to know. Please do that by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM thanks I've added the results now.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities here.

First, there is no assurance that an omnibus significance test on a coefficient will agree with pairwise comparisons based on the factors contributing to the interaction.

Second, you show only the "significance" of the 2 individual coefficients associated with the interaction, not for the interaction term as a whole. A combined Wald test on those coefficients, or a likelihood-ratio test between models with and without the interaction (fit with ML instead of REML) is needed to tell if the interaction as a whole is "significant."

Third, you seem to have specified no multiple-comparison correction for the multiple pairwise comparisons that you performed. It looks like *some* but not all of those might still be "significant" after such comparison. You need to do some multiple-comparison correction; offsetting that somewhat, you don't seem to need all of those pairwise comparisons to test what seems to be your hypothesis. If you select a few comparisons (based on the experimental setup, *not* on the results of the model), multiple-comparison corrections will be less restrictive than when you do all 15.

Fourth, although it's not "statistically significant," the `timepoint0` values of the `conditionTreatment` group are somewhat higher (by the value of the associated coefficient, 0.43) than those of the control group (given by the intercept, 5.2). That's of similar magnitude as the estimated post-intervention treatment effect of ~0.6 units. So even if a *net* difference between the `conditionTreatment` group post intervention differs from that of the control, you have to decide how much that's due to the difference in pre-intervention values.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I am familiar with the idea of omnibus tests differing from pairwise comparisons, but just wondered if there was some other explanation.

Comment: @Biscuity think more carefully about the contrasts that you chose. I think what you want for a null hypothesis is that the `treatment_time1-treatment_time0` _difference_ is the same as the `control_time1-control_time0` difference. Similarly for `time2-time0` within-group differences. You don't need all those pairwise comparisons, which hurt power (with proper correction for multiple comparisons) if they aren't testing pre-specified hypotheses of interest.